# Issue with TypeScript and spread operator

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why this code:

```js
interface TotoInt {
    name: string;
    lastName: string | null;
}

interface TotoInt2 {
    name: string;
    lastName: string;
}

const toto: TotoInt = {
    name: 'toto',
    lastName: Math.random() < 0.5 ? null : "abc",
};

if (toto.lastName) {
    const toto2: TotoInt2 = {
        ...toto,
    };
}
```

produces the following output:

[image]

I would have expected TypeScript to understand that by checking `if (toto.lastName)`, `toto.lastName` would be guaranteed to be non-null, thus allowing the usage of `TotoInt2`.

If I do it this way instead (with the non-null assertion exclamation mark operator), TypeScript doesn't complain:

```
    // if (toto.lastName) {
    //     const toto2: TotoInt2 = {
    //         ...toto,
    //     };
    // }

    const toto2: TotoInt2 = {
        name: toto.name,
        lastName: toto.lastName!,
    };
```

Is this an issue with the way TypeScript (the version I use is 4.8.3) handles the spread operator? Is there no way around the full reconstruction of an object literal with the `!` non nullable operator to make the code accept the usage of `TotoInt2`?

The object is quite simple for demo purposes, but I'm working with a big object, that ideally I could pass into a function that would check for null values and that I thus wouldn't have to reconstruct entirely with a new object literal and `!` non nullable operators.

Comment: It _is_ working correctly. The problem is exactly what it says: those two types aren't compatible. `lastName` can be (and indeed _is_) `null` in `totoInt`, but can't be in `totoInt2`.

Comment: One interface has the shape `{ lastName: lastName: string | null }`  while the other has `{ lastName: string }`. TypeScript cannot guarantee that you're not assigning `null` to a property that expects a string, and hence the warning.

Comment: This is unfortunately a missing feature of TypeScript, see [microsoft/TypeScript#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384).  Type guarding properties only narrows the parent if the parent is of a [discriminated union](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type, which `TotoInt` isn't (fixed to adhere to standard TS naming conventions).  You can work around it by copying the property again like [this](//tsplay.dev/NleA5m) or if you're doing this a lot, building a type guard function like [this](//tsplay.dev/NVkGqm).

Comment: May I edit the code to make `toto`'s `lastName` property be `Math.random() < 0.5 ? null : "abc"`?  People in the comments are getting hung up on the fact that we know the value is `null`, but that doesn't seem to be the issue you're asking about.  ...  Please let me know if my prior comment fully addresses your question. If so, I could write up an answer.  If not, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz if you reply so I'm notified).

Comment: Thank you guys for the prompt answers.
I edited the question! Hope it's clearer!
I will look at your answers tomorrow!

Comment: Ok final edit just now. @jcalz

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you also check again? Sorry if my original post wasn't very clear.

Comment: That's still nothing to do with the spread operator - the compiler just won't change the type of `toto` based on the check of `toto.lastName` per [the earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73806925/issue-with-typescript-and-spread-operator#comment130326338_73806925). Using `!` is wildly inappropriate because it could be (and, again, **is**) null.

Comment: @AleksandrH can you also check again? Sorry if my original post wasn't very clear.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Alright, thank you for the answer.
Although I think I disagree with your statement on the usage of `!` being wildly inappropriate here (at least in the context of the project I'm working on, that I haven't taken the time to explain properly. I could still be wrong though), I will try and understand  @jcalz's answer in depth tomorrow.
Thank you again.

Comment: It doesn't look like you took any of my comments into account, despite your edits. Please look at [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBRDgN). I recommend you change your example code to be the one I mention so that nobody is confused about the explicit setting of the property to `null`. The issue is the missing feature, and various workarounds are suggested in there. When you get a chance, please reply to me via @jcalz and say either "yes, I will make those edits and you can write up your answer" or "no, I will not make those edits or your answer is not appropriate" and we can go from there. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Although I don't understand all the details about your answer yet. I definitely think you perfectly pinpointed the issue. I have made the edits you requested (if you can double check everything is A1 I would appreciate still!). You can go ahead and write up your answer, I will mark it up as the accepted one as soon as it is posted. Thank you so much for your patience and thorough explanations. You seem to be an absolute beast and I think we are lucky to have people like you.

Comment: @jcalz PS: Adding Math.random() < 0.5 ? null : "abc" proved that it wasn't at all about the `toto.lastName` actual set value, but a problem about a broader interface being cast into a narrower one (not sure about the semantics here) that, after typeguard checking a property on the broader interface typed object, should have been automatically narrowed down (`TotoInt.lastName` should have been narrowed down to only `string` in our case), but wasn't because of the missing TypeScript feature as described here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384 ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I'll write up an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Narrowing only happens in particular circumstances.

If you perform a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) on the property `prop` of an object `obj`, such as `(typeof obj.prop === "string")`, you might reasonably expect that if `obj.prop` is narrowed, then `obj` will also be narrowed.  That is, if the type checker now knows that `obj.prop` is a `string` as opposed to `string | null`, then it should also know that `obj` is an object type with a `prop` property of type `string` as opposed to `string | null`.  But generally speaking, this does not happen: if you perform a type guard on `obj.prop`, generally only `obj.prop` will be narrowed.  The type of `obj` itself will stay stubbornly wide.

( An exception to this is when `obj` is of a [discriminated union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) and `prop` is a discriminant property.  But `TotoInt` is not a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) at all, let alone a discriminated one, so checking a property of a `TotoInt` object will only possibly narrow that property and not the parent object. )

There is a suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384) to propagate narrowings of properties up to their parent objects.  But for now, this is not part of the language.

---

Therefore you need to work around it.  The easiest workaround is to copy the narrowed property explicitly, since that property is properly narrowed:

```
if (toto.lastName) {
  const toto2: TotoInt2 = {
    ...toto,
    lastName: toto.lastName // <-- copy over the checked prop again
  }; // okay
}
```

If you find yourself running into this issue often enough, you could write a helper [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) that you call instead of doing the type check.  It's sort of a do-it-yourself implementation of microsoft/TypeScript#42384, and is accordingly clunky:

```
function hasPropType<T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]>(
  obj: T, prop: K, guard: (v: T[K]) => v is V): obj is T & { [P in K]: V } {
  return guard(obj[prop]);
}
```

The idea is that you check the property of key type `K` of an object of type `T` with a type guard function of type `(v: T[K]) => v is V`, where `V` is some narrower type than the known property type `T[K]`.  And this will serve to narrow `obj` if the guard returns true.

For `hasPropType`, you'd like to check if `toto.lastName` is non-null, so you can write the following type guard function:

```
function isNonNullish<T>(x: T): x is NonNullable<T> {
  return x !== undefined && x !== null;
}
```

(You need to write this manually because of another missing feature, see [microsoft/TypeScript#38390](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38390)). Now the check looks like:

```
if (hasPropType(toto, "lastName", isNonNullish)) {
  //const toto: TotoInt & { lastName: string; }
  const toto2: TotoInt2 = { ...toto }; // okay
}
```

You can see that `toto` gets narrowed from `TotoInt` to `TotoInt & {lastName: string}`, which is assignable to `TotoInt2`.

Yes, that's clunky.  The only reason you might want this version is if you have a reason why copying the property multiple times has bad side effects.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-JoXktBkXx6CoAAZEQqA4VsEJgKgBG0OhshNqQ8oQFMsn0YxORkThVEzBx7CkOypCfmA36-rJIy8PYvBSJwIyJKBxFQa4AmoFBfHWWAtnSC0SxOcpqCqep7moP8Xg+HmGRQHA4ArqJ4keeFPhgHZhmoMZELHDkiQAWuwFQKcbaoA0nZUO0-JeT59l0IkeTXHueJoAgTiumgmkwGqpnmfYla9NWjzqHWGieOJnxlYIhgsKwGWVgN3Y4M8aj1hA7wSQyyTBBlM3fJgB5HhyQA)