# Keep type information after creating spread copy

Tags: typescript

I have the problem, that I have a function that gets an object. A field of this object can be null, which I want to handle, and afterwards add a field to this object and return it.

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEYoF4oG8BQVtQGYEsIAbAEwC4oBnYAJ3wDsBzAbQF0oAfKegVyKIDcGAL4YMoSLHgAmFOiw56AQwC2ECtTpMhOPIVIbaDFqxFjcPegGNg+APb08duwAoARkpoU4kBAEpvGXldfFwoFwBCDxoAOgJiEj9g3RxouP0SOTYFbFEcqCsHaigaCEo+YDk0blV1KAAiSjs1KAA5WvqAGigY3uioYR0cUvKiYHSEmLAeSgALF3qAZWboRaMmer8h7FLgHhpHEYqhPKA) you can find a simplified version of it.

The problem that I have is that the assertion that the field is not null is lost after I create the spread clone.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73806925/issue-with-typescript-and-spread-operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bar.field is string[]` information is kept only in `bar.field`, not in `bar` itself

```
type Type1 = {
    field: string[] | null;
}

type Type2 = {
    name: string;
    field: string[]
}

function foo(bar: Type1): Type2 {
    bar.field ??= [];
    const result = { name: "some Name", ...bar, field: bar.field };
    result.field.push("Some String");
    return result;
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73830287/5734961 for more info

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the problem correctly. It seems you are struggling with converting Type1 to Type2? TypeScript's type system is not smart enough to realize that field is not null after using the spread operator. You must use a cast here to silence the compiler.

Does this help?

```js
type Type1 = {
    field: string[] | null;
}

type Type2 = {
    field: string[]
}

function foo(bar: Type1): Type2 {
    if (!bar.field) {
        bar.field = []
        bar.field.push("test");
        return bar as Type2;
    }
    //Option 1
    const result = { ...bar } as Type2;
    result.field.push("Some String");
    return result;

    //Option 2
    const result = { ...bar };
    result.field!.push("Some String");
    return result as Type2;
}
```