# Object spread destructuring works weird in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've got this piece of code:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number
}


interface UnknownPerson {
    age: number;
}

let me: Person = {
    name: "vilgeforc5",
    age: 19
}

// ok
let anotherPerson: UnknownPerson = {
    ...me
}
console.log(anotherPerson.name) /* typescript error. works on runtime */

/* obvious typescript error */
let anotherPerson2: UnknownPerson = {
    name: "vilgeforc5",
    age: 19
}
```

Why is it possible to create `anotherPerson` with destructing, although there are extra fields in `Person` ( name )  ? Is it normal TS behaviour or my compiler options?

Comment: I believe that's because the two types sufficiently overlap in that direction, if you tried spreading an `UnknownPerson` type into a new object of `Person` type, it would raise an error for `Property 'name' is missing`. see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73830287/15291770

Comment: yes, nice. didn't find it , thank you!!!